# What is Identity and state of "java.lang.Enum" type objects in java?

Tags: java, enums

In the below code,

```
class Example{}
Example ex1 = new Example();
Example ex2 = new Example();
bool compareAddress = (ex1 == ex2);
```

here, `compareAddress` gives `false`, because **identity** is the memory address of an object pointed by`ex1` and `ex2`. field values(if any) within object of  type `class Example{}` define **state** of that object.

But in the below code,

```
enum Company{
    EBAY(30), PAYPAL(10), GOOGLE(15), YAHOO(20), ATT(25);
    private int value;

    private Company(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

}
Company x1 = Company.EBAY;
Company x1 = Company.EBAY;
bool compareValues = (x1 == x2);
```

here, `compareValues` gives `true`.

So, What is the identity and state of an object pointed by `x1` and `x2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[An `enum` is a special type of class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

For example

```
enum Company {
    EBAY
}
```

will compile to

```
final class Company extends Enum<Company> {
    public final static Company EBAY = new Company(); // almost, this constructor invocation will have arguments
}
```

The field `EBAY` will, for the remainder of the Java process' life, hold the same reference value, which is a reference to a `Company` instance.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1),

> Because there is only one instance of each enum constant, it is
>   permitted to use the `==` operator in place of the `equals` method when
>   comparing two object references if it is known that at least one of
>   them refers to an `enum` constant.

Comment: compile to? Can you provide access to resource that provide such info?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, see the links provided in the answer. _For each enum constant c declared in the body of the declaration of E, E has an implicitly declared public static final field of type E that has the same name as c. The field has a variable initializer consisting of c, and is annotated by the same annotations as c._

Comment: In my above query, am wrong in saying that  `x1 == x2` is comparing values. `==` actually compares object references. correct?

Comment: @overexchange That is correct, `==` is reference equality.

Comment: as each enum constant is `final`, enum type objects are state less, correct?

Comment: @overexchange No, they can have state. In your example, they have a `value` field. (It's not necessarily good practice, though.)

Comment: When you say "not a good practice", you mean, it is breaking the purpose of enum type, correct? If yes, why java allowed such syntax to include instance level methods/fields in enum type definition?

Comment: The problem isn't with state, it's with mutable state. An enum should represent a constant and constanta shouldn't be mutable. I guess Java wanted to be flexible.